# jQuery hover() and delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating an incremental search using jQuery, the rest of my code works fine, but when I'm trying to highlight only the element being hovered inside the search doesn't work, it starts highlighting all the others. Because the "p" tags are generated AFTER the HTML file is loaded in the browser, they need to be delegated like i wrote on the code.
How could i fix that?

```
 $(document).on("mouseover", "p", function (e) {
        e.target.classList.add("highlight");
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `highlight` class from all other `<p>` elements before adding it to the element hovered on:

```js
$(document).on("mouseover", "p", function(e) {
  $("p").removeClass("highlight");
  e.target.classList.add("highlight");
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: #FF0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a paragraph with some text</p>
<p>This is a paragraph with some text</p>
<p>This is a paragraph with some text</p>
<p>This is a paragraph with some text</p>
<p>This is a paragraph with some text</p>
```